# Is it possible to use CDVInAppBrowser to open local file (says pdf)?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I would like to open a local file in `www` folder using `CDVInAppBrowser`.

It works fine if i tried to open a pdf file from an url. I would like to do the same for a local file in `www` folder. I replace the url with relative link `./myfile.pdf` but it doens't open the browser.

is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified whether it is iphone or android, so my answer will be Yes & No.

It's possible to open a local .pdf file via inappbrowser in iPhone.

but android doesn't support local pdf display via inappbrowser.

Hope it helps.

**Example Usage,**

```
var samplePdfPath= "pdf/sample.pdf";
window.open(samplePdfPath, '_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

Comment: how do i set the url to be? i tried `./myfile.pdf` as i put it in `www` but it doesn't work.